# How to find element in graph?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have the following entities:

1. Form
2. Block
3. Row
4. Cell
5. Field

Root element is `Form`.

Inside `From` is placed `Block`.

`Block` contains some `Rows` and each `Row` can contain some `Cell` with different content inside: `Field` or `Block`, where `Block` it is again nested structure `Block -> Rows -> Cells -> Field/Block`.

It is oriented finite graph from root `Form` and finish vertex `Field` or `Block`.

Only `Block` and `Field` entities have method `getId()` that returns id of vertex. Based on this I build path from root to concrete vertex `(Blcok, Field)`.

I have tried to check if concrete vertex entity `(Block)` is presented in graph by path, so my solution is:

1. Set current vertex (Block) from where we start, set income path of vertexes
2. Get in loop all rows of current vertex (Block)
3. Then inside first loop get all cells from each rows using loop
4. Then get content from each cell (Field, Block)
5. Check if it is Block then get its `id` and compare with incoming path(id)
6. If it is not equal then set found block as current (for loop)
7. Contnues until I can not find path

Code is:

```
function getBlockFieldByPath(block: Block, path: string) {
   let currentBlock = block;
   let irows = 0;
   let jcells = 0;

   while(irows < currentblock.getRows().length) {
       let cells = rows[irows].getCells();
       while(jcells < cells.length) {
           let content = cells[jcells].getContent(); // it is should be Block or Field,

           if (content.getId() == path) {
               return content;
           }

           if (content == Block) {
              currentblock = content; // Because content is Block
           }

          jcells++;
       }
     irows++;
   }   

}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: likely you are not exploring everything since you assign currentBlock an other value

Comment: I reassing `currentBlock` by `content` because `content` is Block type and its id is not path. So it means I need to check content deeply and check all rows,cells inside this content, that why I contimue loop

Comment: I understand why you want to assign, but the way you do it is wrong. because in your outermost loop, you should explore all the rows for some block, say B1. But meanwhile if you assign it an other block, you won't explore all the rows of B1. You may want to read dfs, bfs on wikipedia, but you can tackle the inherent problem linked to indices with simple es6 syntax

Comment: I think I need to have stack of block and add to this stack every time a found block, then recursive call function again, in this case I need three loops, by block, rows, cell, is not?

Comment: if you have a stack, you don't need a recursive call. Just dequeue a block from the stack and push all the block to be explored later, and while loop on your stack. the rows, cells indeed require loop, but what matter the most (if you use a stack) is to push __only the blocks__ to the stack

Comment: Could you share an example using stack and loops? is it three loops?

Comment: see my edited answer @OPV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of abstraction, you have a graph where the nodes are blocks.

Some of those are trivially leaves.

You just want to dfs your graph until you find a block which matches your path string

```
function dfs(block, path) {
  if (block.getId() === path) return block
  let found = null
  block.getRows().find(r => r.getCells().find(bContent => {
    let b = bContent.getContent()
    found = dfs(b, path)
    return found
  }))
  return found
}
```

---

The variation with a stack

```
function dfs(block, path) {
  const stack = [block]
  while (stack.length) {
    const b = stack.pop()
    if (b.getId() === path) return block
    b.getRows().forEach(r => r.getCells().forEach(bContent => {
      let b = bContent.getContent()
      stack.push(b)
    })
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: Second example it is bfs?

Comment: Where do you return found block? Why it is null

Comment: nah it is a dfs except i am exploring children from the end. I also return the block if the getId matches path. And I am returning null if nothing is found. I could also do not return anything (which means undefined) but better be explicit

Comment: So, to summarize, I can use two ways using recursion and loops. They have the same complexity O, right?

Comment: the main algorithms are dfs and bfs. You can implement them using recursion or not (idem with stack). So this make it 4 ways. All of them are linear O(n)